# How to check the case of singular point with polar equation tangent lines

Tags: calculus

The question is to determine the horizontal tangent lines to the polar equation: $r=a(1+\cos \theta)$.  Setting $dy/d\theta = 0$, I get $\theta= \pi, \pi/3,$ and  $5\pi/3.$  I notice that when $\theta =\pi$, then $dx/d\theta $ also is $0$ , thus producing a singular point at which it is inconclusive as to whether there is a horizontal tangent line at $(0,\pi)$ or not. Without graphing (I do know what this simple cardioid looks like when graphed, but often the equations are more complex and no graphing calculators are allowed), how would I check to see if there is a horizontal tangent line there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate  $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to \theta_0} \frac{dy/d
\theta}{dx/d\theta}$.

If the limit exists, then there is no corner. If it is zero, then there is a horizontal tangent line.

Comment: Do you mean if the limit is non-zero then there is no corner?  What would that mean in this case?

Comment: Why is it that if the limit is zero then there is a horizontal tangent line?  Is that a theorem?

Comment: it's mostly intuition. if the limit doesn't exist, then the incoming and outgoing segments of the curves have different slopes, which means a corner. if the limit exists, then then the curve is "smooth" at that point. and if dy/dx=0, obviously, it's a horizontal tangent

Comment: In this case the limit as theta goes to pi is zero over zero so I suppose I would need to use L'hopital's rule.

Comment: @user163862 yes of course, l'hopital is simply a tool to evaluate the limit